# Is SelectObjectContentRequest replaced in AWS SDK 2.x?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk

I don't see this class SelectObjectContentRequest in AWS SDK 2.x.
Is it replaced by a new class or is it not migrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has not been migrated yet to my knowledge. If you'd like to use this feature, then you can still use v1 of the SDK in conjunction with v2 (I do this myself, as `SelectObjectContent` seems to be the easiest method to count the number of lines in an S3 file).

Here is a GitHub issue on the Feature Request (created on November 20, 2018): https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/859